# Count each column if the value is met for a row

Tags: sql

I've been searching far and wide (pun intended) but haven't found a solution yet.

So I got a table with 19 columns.

| pokemon name | against_bug | against_dark | against_dragon | against_electric | against_fairy | against_fight | against_fire | against_flying | against_ghost | against_grass | against_ground | against_ice | against_normal | against_poison | against_psychic | against_rock | against_steel | against_water |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Each of the "against_xxx" columns can have a value of 0,5, 1, 2 or 4.

I want each row to count how many of these columns have a value of 2 or higher in order to determine which pokemon has the most vulnerabilities.

I have no idea how to approach this.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And that have you already tried?

Comment: Consider how much easier it would be if this table was normalised and each column was a row instead, a simple `count(*) & group by` would suffice.

Comment: You can calculate total value of columns in each rows then you will be able to determine which pokemon has the most vulnerabilities `SELECT *, (against_bug + against_dark + ...) AS Sum FROM Table`. If you want to take value greater than 1 then put a where condition `WHERE against_bug >= 2 AND against_dark >= 2 ... `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at Stu's suggestion in the comments on your question. Normalizing your table would be a great help.

Now you need to do something like this:

```
SELECT 
   pokemon, 
   CASE WHEN against_bug >= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
   CASE WHEN against_dark >= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN against_dragon >= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN against_electric >= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
   --[....repeat this for all your columns....]
FROM your_table
```

A normalized table would look like this:

| pokemon | against_type | against_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pickachu | against_bug | 1 |
| Pickachu | against_dark | 2 |
| Pickachu | against_dragon | 0.5 |
| Pickachu | against_electric | 1 |
| Pickachu | (etc) | (etc) |
| Blastoid | against_bug | 1 |
| Blastoid | against_dark | 2 |
| Blastoid | against_dragon | 2 |
| Blastoid | against_electric | 4 |
| Blastoid | (etc) | (etc) |

In this case you could write a much simpler query:

```
SELECT
   pokemon, 
   count(*) AS number_of_vulnerabilities
FROM your_table
WHERE against_value >= 2
GROUP BY pokemon
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution! The `CASE WHEN` solved it for me.
I had been trying to do something similiar before but without the addition between the cases and with a COUNT to nest them.